# using a varible to decide array length for several classes in one class Java

Tags: java, performance, dry, repeat

I have made 3 classes for each level (easy 4*4, medium 6*4, hard 6*6) in a memory game. They consist of the same code, however they have different numbers of the array length and other variables. I want to make the code more efficient by combining the three classes together into only one, do you have any suggestions? If it helps I have pasted the three different classes below :)

Arrays and variables from the 3 different classes:

```
JButton[] button = new JButton[16];
JButton[] button = new JButton[24];
JButton[] button = new JButton[36];

int[] StoreCards = new int[16];
int[] StoreCards = new int[24];
int[] StoreCards = new int[36];

static int[] card = new int[9];
static int[] card = new int[13];
static int[] card = new int[19];
```

Easy Level:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

class EasyWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener {
    JLabel Score = new JLabel("Score: - ");

    JLabel Welcome = new JLabel("Welcome " + StartWindow.user + "!");

    ImageIcon Back = new ImageIcon("mback.png");
    ImageIcon musicicon = new ImageIcon("musicicon.png");
    ImageIcon themeicon = new ImageIcon("themeicon.png");
    ImageIcon difficultyicon = new ImageIcon("difficulty.png");
    ImageIcon pointsicon = new ImageIcon("pointsicon.png");
    ImageIcon studentsicon = new ImageIcon("studentsicon.png");

    JButton AnOtherLevel = new JButton(
            "Click here if you want to change level.");
    JButton Quit = new JButton("Quit Game!");

    JButton[] button = new JButton[16];

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu Settings = new JMenu("Settings");
    JMenu Theme = new JMenu("Theme");
    JMenu Rules = new JMenu("Rules");
    JMenu Creators = new JMenu("Creators");

    JMenuItem Music = new JMenuItem("Music", musicicon);

    JMenuItem Celebrities = new JMenuItem("Celebrities", themeicon);
    JMenuItem Cities = new JMenuItem("Cities", themeicon);
    JMenuItem Memes = new JMenuItem("Memes", themeicon);

    JMenuItem Difficulty = new JMenuItem("Difficulty", difficultyicon);
    JMenuItem Points = new JMenuItem("Points", pointsicon);

    JMenuItem Ava = new JMenuItem("Ava Baghchesara", studentsicon);
    JMenuItem Michelle = new JMenuItem("Michelle Bill", studentsicon);

    int[] StoreCards = new int[16];

    static int[] cardChecker = new int[2];
    static int[] card = new int[9];

    int[] Button = new int[2];

    static int flipped = 0;
    static int score = 0;

    String imageType = ".png";
    String back = ".png";

    JPanel Top = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1, 5, 15));
    JPanel Center = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 5, 5));
    JPanel Bottom = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
    JPanel Right = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 0, 0));
    JPanel Left = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));

    static Container contentArea;

    public EasyWindow() {
        super("User: " + StartWindow.user + " || Easy Level");
        setSize(600, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);

        AnOtherLevel.addActionListener(this);
        Quit.addActionListener(this);

        AnOtherLevel.addMouseListener(this);
        Quit.addMouseListener(this);

        AnOtherLevel.setBackground(Color.white);
        AnOtherLevel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        Quit.setBackground(Color.white);
        Quit.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        add(Top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(Left, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(Center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(Right, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(Bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        Welcome.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        Welcome.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Welcome.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        Top.add(Welcome);
        Top.setBackground(Color.white);

        Center.setBackground(Color.white);

        Right.setBackground(Color.white);

        Right.add(Score);

        Bottom.add(AnOtherLevel);
        Bottom.add(Quit);
        Bottom.setBackground(Color.white);

        for (int n = 0; n <= button.length - 1; n++) {
            button[n] = new JButton();
            Center.add(button[n]);
            button[n].addActionListener(this);
            button[n].setBackground(Color.white);
        }

        contentArea = getContentPane();
        contentArea.add("North", Top);
        contentArea.add("Center", Center);
        contentArea.add("South", Bottom);

        menuBar.add(Settings);
        menuBar.add(Rules);
        menuBar.add(Creators);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        Music.addActionListener(this);

        Theme.addActionListener(this);
        Celebrities.addActionListener(this);
        Cities.addActionListener(this);
        Memes.addActionListener(this);

        Difficulty.addActionListener(this);
        Points.addActionListener(this);

        Ava.addActionListener(this);
        Michelle.addActionListener(this);

        Settings.add(Music);
        Settings.add(Theme);

        Theme.add(Celebrities);
        Theme.add(Cities);
        Theme.add(Memes);

        Rules.add(Difficulty);
        Rules.add(Points);

        Creators.add(Ava);
        Creators.add(Michelle);

        Game();
        flipped = 3;
        Reset();

        setContentPane(contentArea);
        contentArea.setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    public void Game() {
        int number = 0;
        int x = 0;

        ImageIcon image[] = new ImageIcon[15];

        while (x < 16) {
            number = (int) RandomNumbers.GetRandomNumber(8);
            image[number] = new ImageIcon(number + imageType);

            if (card[number] < 2) {
                card[number]++;

                StoreCards[x] = number;
                System.out.println(number + " Number" + "card nr " + x);
                x++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Reset() {
        if (flipped > 2) {
            flipped = 0;

            for (int n = 0; n <= button.length - 1; n++) {
                button[n].setIcon(Back);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Check(int number) {
        if (cardChecker[0] == cardChecker[1]) {
            score = score + 2;
            Score.setText("Score: " + score);
            DisableButtons();

        } else {
            System.out.println("jj");
        }
        if (score == 16) {
            setVisible(false);
            new EndWindow1();
        }
    }

    public void Card1and2(int number, int button) {
        if (flipped == 0) {
            cardChecker[0] = number;
            Button[0] = button;
        }
        if (flipped == 1) {
            cardChecker[1] = number;
            Button[1] = button;

            if (StoreCards[cardChecker[0]] == StoreCards[cardChecker[1]]) {
                if (Button[0] != Button[1])
                    Check(number);
            }
        }
    }

    public void DisableButtons() {
        for (int n = 0; n <= button.length; n++) {
            if (Button[0] == n || Button[1] == n) {
                button[n].setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == AnOtherLevel) {
            setVisible(false);
            new AnOtherWindow();
        }

        if (event.getSource() == Quit) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        for (int n = 0; n <= button.length - 1; n++) {
            if (event.getSource() == button[n]) {

                int number = StoreCards[n];
                button[n].setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));

                Card1and2(number, n);

                flipped++;
                Reset();
            }
        }

        if (event.getSource() == Celebrities) {
            Back = new ImageIcon("ceback.png");
            imageType = "c.png";
        }
        if (event.getSource() == Cities) {
            Back = new ImageIcon("ciback.png");
            imageType = ".jpg";
        }

        if (event.getSource() == Memes) {
            Back = new ImageIcon("mback.png");
            imageType = ".png";
        }
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == AnOtherLevel) {
            AnOtherLevel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            AnOtherLevel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        if (event.getSource() == Quit) {
            Quit.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            Quit.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        AnOtherLevel.setBackground(Color.white);
        AnOtherLevel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        Quit.setBackground(Color.white);
        Quit.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}

public class EasyLevelWindow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EasyWindow win = new EasyWindow();
    }
```

Medium Level:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

class MediumWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener {
    JLabel Score = new JLabel("Score: - ");

    JLabel Welcome = new JLabel("Welcome " + StartWindow.user + "!");

    ImageIcon Back = new ImageIcon("mback.png");
    ImageIcon musicicon = new ImageIcon("musicicon.png");
    ImageIcon themeicon = new ImageIcon("themeicon.png");
    ImageIcon difficultyicon = new ImageIcon("difficulty.png");
    ImageIcon pointsicon = new ImageIcon("pointsicon.png");
    ImageIcon studentsicon = new ImageIcon("studentsicon.png");

    JButton AnOtherLevel = new JButton(
            "Click here if you want to change level.");
    JButton Quit = new JButton("Quit Game!");

    JButton[] button = new JButton[24];

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu Settings = new JMenu("Settings");
    JMenu Theme = new JMenu("Theme");
    JMenu Rules = new JMenu("Rules");
    JMenu Creators = new JMenu("Creators");

    JMenuItem Music = new JMenuItem("Music", musicicon);

    JMenuItem Celebrities = new JMenuItem("Celebrities", themeicon);
    JMenuItem Cities = new JMenuItem("Cities", themeicon);
    JMenuItem Memes = new JMenuItem("Memes", themeicon);

    JMenuItem Difficulty = new JMenuItem("Difficulty", difficultyicon);
    JMenuItem Points = new JMenuItem("Points", pointsicon);

    JMenuItem Ava = new JMenuItem("Ava Baghchesara", studentsicon);
    JMenuItem Michelle = new JMenuItem("Michelle Bill", studentsicon);

    int[] StoreCards = new int[24];

    static int[] cardChecker = new int[2];
    static int[] card = new int[13];

    int[] Button = new int[2];

    static int flipped = 0;
    static int score = 0;

    String imageType = ".png";
    String back = ".png";

    JPanel Top = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 15));
    JPanel Center = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6, 4, 5, 5));
    JPanel Bottom = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));
    JPanel Right = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 0, 0));
    JPanel Left = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));

    static Container contentArea;

    public MediumWindow() {
        super("User: " + StartWindow.user + " || Medium Level");
        setSize(600, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setVisible(true);

        AnOtherLevel.addActionListener(this);
        Quit.addActionListener(this);

        AnOtherLevel.addMouseListener(this);
        Quit.addMouseListener(this);

        AnOtherLevel.setBackground(Color.white);
        AnOtherLevel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        Quit.setBackground(Color.white);
        Quit.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        add(Top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(Left, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(Center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(Right, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(Bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        Welcome.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        Welcome.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Welcome.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        Top.add(Welcome);
        Top.setBackground(Color.white);

        Center.setBackground(Color.white);

        Right.setBackground(Color.white);

        Right.add(Score);

        Bottom.add(AnOtherLevel);
        Bottom.add(Quit);
        Bottom.setBackground(Color.white);

        for (int n = 0; n <= button.length - 1; n++) {
            button[n] = new JButton();
            Center.add(button[n]);
            button[n].addActionListener(this);
            button[n].setBackground(Color.white);
        }

        contentArea = getContentPane();
        contentArea.add("North", Top);
        contentArea.add("Center", Center);
        contentArea.add("South", Bottom);

        menuBar.add(Settings);
        menuBar.add(Rules);
        menuBar.add(Creators);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        Music.addActionListener(this);

        Theme.addActionListener(this);
        Celebrities.addActionListener(this);
        Cities.addActionListener(this);
        Memes.addActionListener(this);

        Difficulty.addActionListener(this);
        Points.addActionListener(this);

        Ava.addActionListener(this);
        Michelle.addActionListener(this);

        Settings.add(Music);
        Settings.add(Theme);

        Theme.add(Celebrities);
        Theme.add(Cities);
        Theme.add(Memes);

        Rules.add(Difficulty);
        Rules.add(Points);

        Creators.add(Ava);
        Creators.add(Michelle);

        Game();
        flipped = 3;
        Reset();

        setContentPane(contentArea);
        contentArea.setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    public void Game() {
        int number = 0;
        int x = 0;

        ImageIcon image[] = new ImageIcon[23];

        while (x < 24) {
            number = (int) RandomNumbers.GetRandomNumber(12);
            image[number] = new ImageIcon(number + imageType);

            if (card[number] < 2) {
                card[number]++;

                StoreCards[x] = number;
                System.out.println(number + " Number" + "card nr " + x);
                x++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Reset() {
        if (flipped > 2) {
            flipped = 0;

            for (int n = 0; n <= button.length - 1; n++) {
                button[n].setIcon(Back);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Check(int number) {
        if (cardChecker[0] == cardChecker[1]) {
            score = score + 2;
            Score.setText("Score: " + score);
            DisableButtons();

        } else {
            System.out.println("jj");
        }
        if (score == 24) {
            setVisible(false);
            new EndWindow1();
        }
    }

    public void Card1and2(int number, int button) {
        if (flipped == 0) {
            cardChecker[0] = number;
            Button[0] = button;
        }
        if (flipped == 1) {
            cardChecker[1] = number;
            Button[1] = button;

            if (StoreCards[cardChecker[0]] == StoreCards[cardChecker[1]]) {
                if (Button[0] != Button[1])
                    Check(number);
            }
        }
    }

    public void DisableButtons() {
        for (int n = 0; n <= button.length; n++) {
            if (Button[0] == n || Button[1] == n) {
                button[n].setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == AnOtherLevel) {
            setVisible(false);
            new AnOtherWindow();
        }

        if (event.getSource() == Quit) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        for (int n = 0; n <= button.length - 1; n++) {
            if (event.getSource() == button[n]) {

                int number = StoreCards[n];
                button[n].setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));

                Card1and2(number, n);

                flipped++;
                Reset();
            }
        }

        if (event.getSource() == Celebrities) {
            Back = new ImageIcon("ceback.png");
            imageType = "c.png";
        }
        if (event.getSource() == Cities) {
            Back = new ImageIcon("ciback.png");
            imageType = ".jpg";
        }

        if (event.getSource() == Memes) {
            Back = new ImageIcon("mback.png");
            imageType = ".png";
        }
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == AnOtherLevel) {
            AnOtherLevel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            AnOtherLevel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        if (event.getSource() == Quit) {
            Quit.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            Quit.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        AnOtherLevel.setBackground(Color.white);
        AnOtherLevel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        Quit.setBackground(Color.white);
        Quit.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}

public class MediumLevelWindow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MediumWindow win = new MediumWindow();
    }
}
```

Hard Level:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JMenu;
    import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
    import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

    class HardWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener {
        JLabel Score = new JLabel("Score: - ");

        JLabel Welcome = new JLabel("Welcome " + StartWindow.user + "!");

        ImageIcon Back = new ImageIcon("mback.png");
        ImageIcon musicicon = new ImageIcon("musicicon.png");
        ImageIcon themeicon = new ImageIcon("themeicon.png");
        ImageIcon difficultyicon = new ImageIcon("difficulty.png");
        ImageIcon pointsicon = new ImageIcon("pointsicon.png");
        ImageIcon studentsicon = new ImageIcon("studentsicon.png");

        JButton AnOtherLevel = new JButton(
                "Click here if you want to change level.");
        JButton Quit = new JButton("Quit Game!");

        JButton[] button = new JButton[36];

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu Settings = new JMenu("Settings");
        JMenu Theme = new JMenu("Theme");
        JMenu Rules = new JMenu("Rules");
        JMenu Creators = new JMenu("Creators");

        JMenuItem Music = new JMenuItem("Music", musicicon);

        JMenuItem Celebrities = new JMenuItem("Celebrities", themeicon);
        JMenuItem Cities = new JMenuItem("Cities", themeicon);
        JMenuItem Memes = new JMenuItem("Memes", themeicon);

        JMenuItem Difficulty = new JMenuItem("Difficulty", difficultyicon);
        JMenuItem Points = new JMenuItem("Points", pointsicon);

        JMenuItem Ava = new JMenuItem("Ava Baghchesara", studentsicon);
        JMenuItem Michelle = new JMenuItem("Michelle Bill", studentsicon);

        int[] StoreCards = new int[36];

        static int[] cardChecker = new int[2];
        static int[] card = new int[19];

        int[] Button = new int[2];

        static int flipped = 0;
        static int score = 0;

        String imageType = ".png";
        String back = ".png";

        JPanel Top = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 15));
        JPanel Center = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6, 6, 5, 5));
        JPanel Bottom = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));
        JPanel Right = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 0, 0));
        JPanel Left = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));

        static Container contentArea;

        public HardWindow() {
            super("User: " + StartWindow.user + " || Hard Level");
            setSize(780, 730);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setResizable(true);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setVisible(true);

            AnOtherLevel.addActionListener(this);
            Quit.addActionListener(this);

            AnOtherLevel.addMouseListener(this);
            Quit.addMouseListener(this);

            AnOtherLevel.setBackground(Color.white);
            AnOtherLevel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

            Quit.setBackground(Color.white);
            Quit.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

            add(Top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(Left, BorderLayout.WEST);
            add(Center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(Right, BorderLayout.EAST);
            add(Bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            Welcome.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 30));
            Welcome.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            Welcome.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

            Top.add(Welcome);
            Top.setBackground(Color.white);

            Center.setBackground(Color.white);

            Right.setBackground(Color.white);

            Right.add(Score);

            Bottom.add(AnOtherLevel);
            Bottom.add(Quit);
            Bottom.setBackground(Color.white);

            for (int n = 0; n <= button.length - 1; n++) {
                button[n] = new JButton();
                Center.add(button[n]);
                button[n].addActionListener(this);
                button[n].setBackground(Color.white);
            }

            contentArea = getContentPane();
            contentArea.add("North", Top);
            contentArea.add("Center", Center);
            contentArea.add("South", Bottom);

            menuBar.add(Settings);
            menuBar.add(Rules);
            menuBar.add(Creators);

            setJMenuBar(menuBar);

            Music.addActionListener(this);

            Theme.addActionListener(this);
            Celebrities.addActionListener(this);
            Cities.addActionListener(this);
            Memes.addActionListener(this);

            Difficulty.addActionListener(this);
            Points.addActionListener(this);

            Ava.addActionListener(this);
            Michelle.addActionListener(this);

            Settings.add(Music);
            Settings.add(Theme);

            Theme.add(Celebrities);
            Theme.add(Cities);
            Theme.add(Memes);

            Rules.add(Difficulty);
            Rules.add(Points);

            Creators.add(Ava);
            Creators.add(Michelle);

            Game();
            flipped = 3;
            Reset();

            setContentPane(contentArea);
            contentArea.setBackground(Color.white);
        }

        public void Game() {
            int number = 0;
            int x = 0;

            ImageIcon image[] = new ImageIcon[35];

            while (x < 36) {
                number = (int) RandomNumbers.GetRandomNumber(18);
                image[number] = new ImageIcon(number + imageType);

                if (card[number] < 2) {
                    card[number]++;

                    StoreCards[x] = number;
                    System.out.println(number + " Number" + "card nr " + x);
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Reset() {
            if (flipped > 2) {
                flipped = 0;

                for (int n = 0; n <= button.length - 1; n++) {
                    button[n].setIcon(Back);
                }
            }
        }

        public void Check(int number) {
            if (cardChecker[0] == cardChecker[1]) {
                score = score + 2;
                Score.setText("Score: " + score);
                DisableButtons();

            } else {
                System.out.println("jj");
            }
            if (score == 36) {
                setVisible(false);
                new EndWindow1();
            }
        }

        public void Card1and2(int number, int button) {
            if (flipped == 0) {
                cardChecker[0] = number;
                Button[0] = button;
            }
            if (flipped == 1) {
                cardChecker[1] = number;
                Button[1] = button;

                if (StoreCards[cardChecker[0]] == StoreCards[cardChecker[1]]) {
                    if (Button[0] != Button[1])
                        Check(number);
                }
            }
        }

        public void DisableButtons() {
            for (int n = 0; n <= button.length; n++) {
                if (Button[0] == n || Button[1] == n) {
                    button[n].setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (event.getSource() == AnOtherLevel) {
                setVisible(false);
                new AnOtherWindow();
            }

            if (event.getSource() == Quit) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

            for (int n = 0; n <= button.length - 1; n++) {
                if (event.getSource() == button[n]) {

                    int number = StoreCards[n];
                    button[n].setIcon(new ImageIcon(number + imageType));

                    Card1and2(number, n);

                    flipped++;
                    Reset();
                }
            }

            if (event.getSource() == Celebrities) {
                Back = new ImageIcon("ceback.png");
                imageType = "c.png";
            }
            if (event.getSource() == Cities) {
                Back = new ImageIcon("ciback.png");
                imageType = ".jpg";
            }

            if (event.getSource() == Memes) {
                Back = new ImageIcon("mback.png");
                imageType = ".png";
            }
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.getSource() == AnOtherLevel) {
                AnOtherLevel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                AnOtherLevel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }

            if (event.getSource() == Quit) {
                Quit.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                Quit.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            AnOtherLevel.setBackground(Color.white);
            AnOtherLevel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            Quit.setBackground(Color.white);
            Quit.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    }

    public class HardLevelWindow {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            HardWindow win = new HardWindow();


}
}
```

Comment: You should try first, and then ask a question about something you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Parent` class e.g.: `BaseGame` which is abstract. Like that:

```
    public abstract class BaseGame {

        private abstract int[] getStoreCards();

        private abstract JButton[] getButtons();

        private abstract int[] getCards();

        ... your other code goes here

    }
```

And then you can create your child classes where you implement these methods, e.g:

```
public class EasyGame {

    @Override
    private int[] getStoreCards() {
        return new int[16];
    }

    @Override
    private int[] getCards() {
        return new int[9];
    }

    @Override
    private JButton[] getButtons() {
        return new JButton[16];
    }
}
```

So everywhere in your code where you usually initalize your arrays, use those methods instead.

```
int[] Button = new int[2];
```

becomes

```
getButtons();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), like so:

```
ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();

//...

for (int n = 0; n < boardSize; n++) {
    JButton button = new JButton();
    buttons.add(button); // add to the end of the expandable list
    Center.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    button.setBackground(Color.white);
}
```

where `boardSize` is a parameter to your constructor specifying the size.